# Can I create a subversion branch that tracks trunk?

Tags: svn

I would like to create a branch of one of the modules in my SVN repository.  This module contains several sub-modules.  I would like some of these sub-modules to be divergent in the branch, but other sub-modules should maintain consistency with trunk.

So, for example, sub-module A should be divergent between BRANCH and TRUNK, but sub-module B should not.  A change committed to A in BRANCH will not appear in TRUNK, but a change committed to B in BRANCH will automatically be reflected in TRUNK.  I'd like this to happen automatically, without me having to force relevant changes from BRANCH into TRUNK.

Is this something that is possible to do using subversion?

Comment: How would the automatic merge from branch to trunk resolve the conflicts you would get if the same lines are modified in both branches?

Comment: Well, I was hoping that they would be the same files, so conflicts would be managed the same way conflicts are managed when two people are committing to the same branch.  The analogy that I am thinking of here would be a symbolic link between the branch and trunk for the specific modules.  So, a commit to one would also commit to the other (really, it is only one commit, just like changing a file, all symlinks are automatically updated).

Comment: Look for externals (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html). But they're often hard to really understand and handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even though this might be *technically* possible (perhaps by using externals as mentioned by JB in comments or maybe some obscure svn feature), I don't think there's really any viable solution for what you're looking for.

What about separating the modules into different svn paths like so?

```
MainApp
  /trunk - would depend on ModuleB/branches/branch1
  /branches
    /branchA - would depend on ModuleA/branches/branch1
  /tags
ModuleA
  /trunk
  /branches
    /branch1
  /tags
ModuleB
  /trunk
  /branches
    /branch1
  /tags
```

That way, changes to Module B would affect MainApp/trunk. Changes to Module A would affect MainApp/branches/branchA.

This structure also usually works well with build tools.

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  Something like this is another avenue that I am exploring.  I would branch only the module that needs to change, and then users would pull in all the other modules from TRUNK, except for the one that needs to branch.  The problem I have is how to set this up inside bamboo.  Bamboo seems to want to monitor a single utl for changes and wants to check out from a single url, so checking out both a branch and trunk does not seem possible from what I can tell.

Comment: Oh, I see. I haven't used bamboo yet. I use Maven and Hudson, and this kind of svn project structure usually works well for me. Can you set up ModuleB as it's own project in Bamboo, maybe? Then the Main project can depend on ModuleB.jar or something?

Comment: Snooping around some more on the Atlassian forums and it doesn't seem like this is possible, but I am waiting to hear back from someone there.  I am building an Eclipse update site, and they like to be built all in one piece, so splitting into multiple builds is not really an option.

Comment: I eventually decided to follow something like what Dave suggests above.  I created 2 bamboo builds for each version.  One contains the code modules that branch for each version and the other contains the code modules that are shared between versions.  The first build checks the code out and places it in a location where the second build can access it.  And the first build triggers the second to run after it completes successfully.  This appears to be working.  Thanks for your help.